# Why can't I remove certain item from a nested list when setting some criteria?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to remove some unwanted result of my nested list but when I tried this:

```
ppp =  [[132],[127, 236],[133, 259]]
for p in ppp:
    if len(p) == 2:
        ppp.remove(p)
print(ppp)
```

The output was:

```
[[132], [133, 259]]
```

It did remove`[127,236]`but it didn't remove `[133, 259]` that should also be removed.

How should that be happened?

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed to remove elements from `list` during iterating over it. That's why you got so strange behavior here - after removing `[127, 236]` collection size decreased, 3rd element became 2nd and loop finished because it thought that code reached end of `list` (processed 2 elements out of 2). Corrected code:

```
ppp = [[132], [127, 236], [133, 259]]
ppp = [p for p in ppp if len(p) != 2]  # list comprehension does the trick
print(ppp)
```

Output:

> [[132]]